# If Websocket connection can't be established do something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I'm currently running into a problem you guys might be able to help me with..

I'm using websockets to connect to a custom server. Now i want to integrate a second Server IP if the first one isn't available.

How is it possible to detect, that the connection couldn't be made because the server isn't reachable? When I enter a wrong ws://url in my script, Chrome for example gives me the following error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://1234/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

in Firefox it's something complete different. Do you guys of any method to catch this error with Javascript?

Basically when the ws:// url can't be reached, i want to change a variable with a different Server-IP and try it with this one again...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can always fallback to an ajax long polling aproach.

Comment: hey @3boll , thank you! could you explain a more detailed? i never worked with ajax long polling.. a google research didn't help me much as well..

Comment: Socket.IO (http://socket.io/) is a project that does automatic fallback to long-polling if a browser does not support websockets, so you might want to look into that if you need it.

Comment: oh, its not a about the problem that the user has no websockets.. im using websockets to connect to a certain url, ws://127.0.0.1, now if this host wouldn't be available for some reason, the same error appears as if you would us a ws:// thats not existent.

I need to catch this certain type of error to switch to try another ws:// IP after that... Basically: If IP1 is down, try IP2... 

it fires back the "onClose" Event, which is right so far.. but it would be better if there's a way for just "server not available". im using the onClose event for other stuff which would conflict in a reconnect.

Comment: Yep, I realize, and was typing up a (generic) answer, but the comment above didn't end up being too helpful so I thought I'd chip in here as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no way to catch the problem on instantiation, even though the magical JavaScript black box somehow seems to know the problem occurs on the new WebSocket.

To detect this error, use the following:

```
ws = new WebSocket(server);

ws.onerror = function (evt) {
    if (ws.readyState == 3) {
        //Connection closed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @orbitbot,

I'm using a framework called jwebsocket (jwebsocket.org). My Code is basically this:

```js
 serverstate = "0";
 console.log(serverstate);

function logon() {
 
 
 if(serverstate == "0") {
  lURL = "wss://testurl-one:9797";
 } else if (serverstate == "1") {
  lURL = "wss://testurl-two:9797";
 }
 
 
 var gUsername = "user";
 var lPassword = "pass";

 console.log( "Connecting to " + lURL + " and console.logging in as '" + gUsername + "'..." );
 
 var lRes = lWSC.logon( lURL, gUsername, lPassword, {

  // OnOpen callback
  OnOpen: function( aEvent ) {
   console.log( "jWebSocket connection established." );
  },
  
  // OnMessage callback
  OnMessage: function( aEvent, aToken ) {
   var lDate = "";
   if( aToken.date_val ) {
    lDate = jws.tools.ISO2Date( aToken.date_val );
   }
   console.log( "jWebSocket '" + aToken.type + "' token received, full message: '" + aEvent.data + "' " + lDate + "" );
   console.log(aToken);
     
   }
   
  },
  
  // OnClose callback
  OnClose: function( aEvent ) {
   console.log( "Disconnected from Server" );
   console.log("Using next server..");
   serverstate = "1";
   console.log(serverstate);
   console.log("Trying to connect to next server");
   logon();
  },
  
  // OnClose callback
  OnError: function( aEvent ) {
   console.log ("Some error appeared");
  }
 
 });
  
 console.log( lWSC.resultToString( lRes ) );
}
```

Of course this would work so far. My Problem is that im using websockets to open a connection, get some information, and after that close the connection again.

since this code will always be fired if the server connection is closed (which in many cases i want to..) i can't use it like that...

any other ideas on this problem ?

Comment: I assume that you will get similar error events to the try/catch suggestion above in either the `OnClose` or `OnError` callbacks, or both, so you  need to discover what the problem is in either block by inspecting `aEvent`. The event probably has a standardized string (which may vary depending on browser) if not a error number to check.

Depending on what error message you get, decide if you need to exit or try another url. The code structure is a bit problematic for retrying different urls, since you shouldn't directly put `lWSC.logon(` in a method and call it in OnError/OnClose.

Comment: yep.. good hint! i tried this, but unfortunately the aEvent just outputs :

CloseEvent {reason: "", code: 1006, wasClean: false, path: NodeList[0], cancelBubble: false…}

.. the code is always the same, and the reason is always empty.. no matter if the connection got closed because i wanted to, or because of that the server wasn't available..

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your code is something like this,

```
var host = 'ws://a.real.websocket.url';
var socket = new WebSocket(host);
```

... you just need to surround the call to `new WebSocket` with a try/catch block, something like this

```
try {
  var socket = new WebSocket(host);
} catch (e) {
  // inspect e to understand why there was an error
  // and connect to another url if necessary
}
```

That being said, it might be easier to work with a websockets library such as Socket.IO or SockJS (https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client), which then would change your reconnection code logic to whatever the libraries provide.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the word "Exception" shouldn't be there: Syntax Error

Comment: Yeah, that would be the usual indicator :) Edited to remove.

Comment: did not work for me (no exception is thrown if the server is down).

Answer (score -1):

I got it.. for everyone else who's interested:

When connection is made you receive a message from there server. So if the server is not available.. there'll be no message. So i just added a variable to the "OnMessage" Part.. and in the disconnect i check if a message was received. If not the server isn't there.. if yes, everything works fine..